# Can't add Bundle Products to a created Bundle in CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2015

I modified the Product entity form for a particular CRM environment in 2015. However, I don't see a + sign to add Bundle Products to it.

However, in my trial environment, I'm easily able to do so.

Not sure what went wrong. I checked for both Draft bundle and Active Bundle.

PS: I'm not using Product Family.

Comment: I was able to resolve this. I was not using the OOB Product form for the same that led me to this error.